# Adding two binary numbers

Tags: c++

I want to improve this code with better logic and using STL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void addition(const std::vector<int>& A,
              const std::vector<int>& B,
                    std::vector<int>& C)
{
   int size_A = A.size();
   int size_B = B.size();
   int max_size;
   if (size_A >= size_B)
   {
      max_size = size_A;
   }
   else
   {
      max_size = size_B;
   }

   int carry = 0, sum = 0;

   int i = size_A - 1, j = size_B - 1, k = max_size;
   C.resize(k + 1);

   while ( i >= 0 && j >= 0 && k >= 0)
   {
      sum = A[i] + B[j] + carry;

      if (sum == 0)
      {
         carry = 0;
         C[k] = 0;
      }
      else if (sum == 1)
      {
         carry = 0;
         C[k] = 1;
      }
      else if (sum == 2)
      {
         carry = 1;
         C[k] = 0;
      }
      else if (sum == 3)
      {
         carry = 1;
         C[k] = 1;
      }
      i--;
      j--;
      k--;
   }
  //if size of first binary number is greter than first
  if (max_size == size_A)
  {
     while (i >= 0 && k >= 0)
     {
        sum = A[i] + carry;

        if (sum == 0)
        {
           carry = 0;
           C[k] = 0;
        }
        else if (sum == 1)
        {
           carry = 0;
           C[k] = 1;
        }
        else if (sum == 2)
        {
           carry = 1;
           C[k] = 0;
        }
        else if (sum == 3)
        {
           carry = 1;
           C[k] = 1;
        }
        i--;
        k--;
     }
  }
  //If size of second binary number is greater than first
  else if (max_size == size_B)
  {
     while (j >= 0 && k >= 0)
     {
       sum = B[j] + carry;

       if (sum == 0)
       {
          carry = 0;
          C[k] = 0;
       }
       else if (sum == 1)
       {
          carry = 0;
          C[k] = 1;
       }
       else if (sum == 2)
       {
          carry = 1;
          C[k] = 0;
       }
       else if (sum == 3)
       {
          carry = 1;
          C[k] = 1;
       }
       j--;
       k--;
     }
  }
  C[0] = carry;
}

int main()
{
   int n1, n2, val;
   std::cout << "Enter the  number of bits for first binary numbers \n";
   std::cin >> n1;
   std::cout << "Enter the  number of bits for second binary numbers \n";
   std::cin >> n2;

   std::vector<int> A;
   std::vector<int> B;
   std::vector<int> C;

   std::cout << "Enter bits for first binary number \n";
   for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
   {
      std::cin >> val;
      A.push_back(val);
   }

   std::cout << "Enter bits for second binary number \n";
   for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
   {
     std::cin >> val;
     B.push_back(val);
   }

   std::cout << "First number    : ";
   for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
   {
      std::cout << A[i];
   }

   std::cout << "\nSecond number   : ";
   for (int i = 0; i < B.size(); i++)
   {
      std::cout << B[i];
   }

   addition(A, B, C);

   std::cout << "\nResult          : ";
   for (int i = 0; i < C.size(); i++)
   {
     std::cout << C[i];
   }
   std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This might make life easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/88934/14065

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write DRY code:

DRY - Don't repeat yourself.

```
std::cout << "Enter bits for first binary number \n";
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
   std::cin >> val;
   A.push_back(val);
}

std::cout << "Enter bits for second binary number \n";
for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
{
  std::cin >> val;
  B.push_back(val);
}
```

These two bits of code are way to similar. Make a function that does this work and pass as parameters any differences.

Highest order bit is where?

```
  std::cin >> val;
  B.push_back(val);
```

With this code your most significant bit is at location 0. This gives you no room to expand the number. Put the least significant bit at 0 and the more significant bits at higher locations. This will make it easier to do the standard maths operations in the long run.

This looks like a switch:

```
  if (sum == 0)
  {
     carry = 0;
     C[k] = 0;
  }
  else if (sum == 1)
  {
     carry = 0;
     C[k] = 1;
  }
  else if (sum == 2)
  {
     carry = 1;
     C[k] = 0;
  }
  else if (sum == 3)
  {
     carry = 1;
     C[k] = 1;
  }
```

I would write as:

```
  switch (sum) {
      case 0: carry = 0;C[k] = 0;break;
      case 1: carry = 0;C[k] = 1;break;
      case 2: carry = 1;C[k] = 0;break;
      case 3: carry = 1;C[k] = 1;break;
      default: throw std::exception("Something very wrong happened");
  }
```

Another case of DRY:

```
  while ( i >= 0 && j >= 0 && k >= 0)
  {
      sum = A[i] + B[j] + carry;
      // STUFF
      k--;i--;j--;
  }
  //if size of first binary number is greter than first
  if (max_size == size_A)
  {
     while (i >= 0 && k >= 0)
     {
        sum = A[i] + carry;
        // STUFF
        k--;i--;
     }
  }
  //If size of second binary number is greater than first
  else if (max_size == size_B)
  {
     while (j >= 0 && k >= 0)
     {
       sum = B[j] + carry;
       // STUFF
      k--;j--;
     }
  }
```

Not only can all the "stuff" by factored out into its own function. But those three loops can be combined into a single loop.

```
  for(;k >= 0;--k)
  {
      int a = (i > 0) ? A[i--] : 0
      int b = (j > 0) ? B[j--] : 0;
      sum = a + b + carry;
      // STUFF
  }
```

Comment: I thought of a switch when I read that, but then thought `carry = a&b; result = a^b;`.  You might even be able to use `std::transform()` with a stateful functor to hold the carry.

Answer (score 5):

#### Code Organization

Rather than having multiple sections of code that execute conditionally depending on whether A is smaller than B or vice versa, I'd start by finding the smaller and larger of the two inputs, and then operate on them (independent of whether they were originally A or B).

#### Return what's Created

I'd also have the `Addition` return the result it creates. The days of needing to avoid returning large values to avoid needless copying are pretty much a bit of ancient lore, better forgotten.

#### Use Verbs when appropriate

You `addition` should really be `add`--you're dealing with a function. It *does* something, so the appropriate kind of work to use as its name is a verb.

#### Store the Data little-endian

Most of the time, it's much easier to deal with data being stored little-endian. That is, the least significant bit is stored as element 0 of each vector, element 1 is more significant, and on up to the maximum subscript storing the most significant bit of that number.

#### Use Functions where Appropriate

Right now, your `main` has a number of lines of code to read in some bits, write out some bits, and so on. At least IMO, each of these chunks of code should become a function.

```
std::string show(std::vector<int> const &t) {
    std::string ret;
    for (auto p = t.rbegin(); p != t.rend(); p++)
        ret += *p ? '1' : '0';
    return ret;
}

std::vector<int> read_bin(std::string_view const &prompt, int size) {
    std::vector<int> ret;
    std::cout << prompt << ": ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int val;
        std::cin >> val;
        ret.push_back(val);
    }
    return { ret.rbegin(), ret.rend() };
}
```

#### Use Appropriate Logic

Right now, you're implementation of addition depends on a having an addition operator that already knows how to add two bits and create a carry out to the next bit from them. IOW, your implementation depends on the pre-existence of exactly what it's supposed to implement. Unfortunately, the task isn't quite as simple as @TobySpeight's comment would tend to imply. While he's nearly correct that the result can use an `xor`, it has to be a 3-way XOR, not just two way (the inputs are the previous carry, A[i] and B[i]).

Generating the carry correctly is a bit trickier: since you have three inputs, the carry needs to be set of any two of the inputs is set. Unfortunately, the only way I know of to do that is to enumerate the three possibilities:

```
carry = (A[i] & B[i]) | (A[i] & carry) | (B[i] & carry);
```

One possibility that might seem obvious would be to just count the results from the three sub-expressions there--but that gets us back to addition depending on addition, since counting is just addition in disguise.

#### Consider Using a class to store and Manipulate a number

Instead of having an `add`, `read_bin` and `show` to manipulate data in a couple of vectors, consider creating a class that stores the data, and implements the operations on the numbers using the normal conventions (`+` to add, `<<` to display, `>>` to read.

```
class binary {
    std::vector<int> data;

    int &operator[](std::size_t index) { return data[index]; }
    int const &operator[](std::size_t index) const { return data[index]; }
public:
    auto size() const { return data.size(); }

    binary() = default;

    binary(size_t size) : data(size) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, binary const &t) {
        std::string ret;
        for (auto p = t.data.rbegin(); p != t.data.rend(); p++)
            ret += *p ? '1' : '0';
        return os << ret;
    }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, binary &b) {
        std::vector<int> ret;
        b.data.resize(is.width());

        for (auto p = b.data.rbegin(); p != b.data.rend(); p++) {
            int val;
            is >> val;
            *p = val ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return is;
    }

    friend binary operator+(binary const &A, binary const &B) {
        binary const &smaller = A.size() < B.size() ? A : B;
        binary const &larger = &smaller == &A ? B : A;

        binary ret(larger.size() + 1);

        int carry = 0;
        int sum;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < smaller.size(); i++) {
            sum = smaller[i] ^ larger[i] ^ carry;
            carry = (smaller[i] & larger[i]) | (smaller[i] & carry) | (larger[i] & carry);

            ret.data[i] = sum;
        }

        for (; i < larger.size(); i++) {
            ret.data[i] = larger[i] ^ carry;
            carry &= larger[i];
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Using these, our `main` becomes somewhat more manageable as well:

```
int main() {
   int n1, n2, val;
   std::cout << "Enter the  number of bits for first binary numbers \n";
   std::cin >> n1;
   std::cout << "Enter the  number of bits for second binary numbers \n";
   std::cin >> n2;

   std::cout << "Enter bits for first number: ";
   binary A;
   std::cin >> std::setw(n1) >> A;

   std::cout << "Enter bits for second number: ";
   binary B;
   std::cin >> std::setw(n2) >> B;

   auto C = A + B;
   auto width = C.size();

   std::cout << std::setw(15) << "First number: " << std::setw(width) << A << "\n";
   std::cout << std::setw(15) << "Second number: " << std::setw(width) << B << "\n";
   std::cout << std::setw(15) << "Sum: " << std::setw(width) << C << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, I'd add replacing

```
if (sum == 0)
{
   carry = 0;
   C[k] = 0;
}
else if (sum == 1)
{
   carry = 0;
   C[k] = 1;
}
else if (sum == 2)
{
   carry = 1;
   C[k] = 0;
}
else if (sum == 3)
{
   carry = 1;
   C[k] = 1;
}
```

with

```
C[k]  = sum % 2;
carry = sum / 2;
```

or, perhaps better:

```
C[k]  = sum & 1;
carry = (sum & 2) >> 1;
```

Comment: This retains the fundamental problem of the original: it's using addition to implement addition. If you already have working addition, there's no point in doing this at all.